# Xl to CS conversion doubles it size using MS Excel

Tags: android, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I want to convert excel to DB file in android application.

Excel has 90k records,

1. I am using MS Excel to convert xlsx to CSV file.
2. I am using DB Browser for Sqlite for converting CSV to Db file.
3. I am using SQlite db for Android DB.

As a first step,i am converting excel file of size to CSV file,On converting excel file which has size of 15 MB,When i save it as CSV file it turns to 31.2 MB,It size increases almost double.

Previously some other person have created CSV file of 15 MB in Size from excel file of size  10.5 MB.I am not sure whether what sort of process in which it has been achieved.

Is there any way to reduce the file size when converting to CSV file?

I tried changing to Text in format cell options, it just reduced .5 MB

Comment: xlsx files are zip compressed XML. When you convert to plaintext CSV, it's uncompressed. Not much you can do about that, if you need it like that. You're not shipping that CSV with your app, though, are you?

Comment: I am converting it to Sqlite file and then using it in app

Answer (score 0):

XLSX and CSV are extremely different file formats so I'm not surprised in the least that the file size has practically doubled.

XLSX files are XML based, CSV is just text with no compression.  Take any XSLX file, change the extension to .ZIP and then open it, you can see the difference and you'll also notice that as a ZIP file, it opens, therefore, it's compressed.

Also, there's no direct correlation between the size of an XLSX file and what it converts to when saved as a CSV.  The way data is stored in the XML format is extremely clever goes above and beyond to try and reduce the size of the file when saved.

CSV, not so much!

Not sure if that helps.